# <input type=button /> Changing Background color

Tags: html, css, validation, button

this is my button [(this is my Scipt)](https://codepen.io/lukas-will-per/pen/LJMRVr):

```
<ol class="cabin fuselage">
        <li class="row 1">
            <ol class="seats" >
                <li class="seat">           
                    <input  type="button" id="1A"  value="<?php $sql="SELECT Name FROM autoreservierung WHERE Platz='Fahrer'"; $query = mysql_query($sql,$connection);  $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); echo $result['Name'];?>"  />
                </li>
                <li class="seat">
                    <input type="button" id="1B" value="<?php $sql="SELECT Name FROM autoreservierung WHERE Platz='Beifahrer'"; $query = mysql_query($sql,$connection); $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); echo $result['Name'];?>"  />
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
```

I want to have the color stay red if the value is empty and green if there is any value ( value="" vs value="blasamplename" )

Is there a way?

EDIT:

I figured out that:

```
input[value=""] 
{
background: #bada55;
}
```

Will make the text field greenish, is there a way to do that for the whole parent input?

Comment: Regarding your edit...No, this is not possible with CSS yet. There is no Parent selector. You will need Javascript. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

Removed your php code. Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/agamj474/pen/xamRZN

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="button"]').each(function(i, d){
    var el = $(d);
    var color = el.val() ? "red" :"green";
    el.parent("li").css("background", color);
  })
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after 
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html 
{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.car 
{
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.caption 
{
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.caption:before 
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-left: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.caption h1 
{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 100px auto 35px auto;
}

.fuselage 
{
  border-right: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-left: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #d8d8d8;
}

ol 
{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.seats 
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

input[type=button] 
{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: Transparent;
 text-align: center;
 border: none;
}

.seat,.seatlow:active
{
 background: #bada55; 
}
  



.seat  , .seatlow
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: #F42536;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.seat:before, .seatlow:before 
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  top: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.seat:hover , .seatlow:hover 
{
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #5C6AFF;
}

.seatlow:nth-child(1) 
{
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}
.seatlow:nth-child(2) 
{
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}
.seat:nth-child(1) 
{
  margin-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Autoreservierung</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="car">
   <div class="caption">
   <h1>Please select a seat</h1>
  </div>
  <ol class="cabin fuselage">
   <li class="row 1">
    <ol class="seats" >
     <li class="seat">   
      <input  type="button" id="1A"  value=""  />
     </li>
     <li class="seat">
      <input type="button" id="1B" value=""  />
     </li>
    </ol>
   </li>
<br/><br/>
   <li class="row 2">
     <ol class="seats" >
      <li class="seatlow">
       <input type="button" id="2A" value="xyz" />
      </li>
      <li class="seatlow">
       <input type="button" id="2B" value="xyz"/>
      </li>
      <li class="seatlow">
       <input type="button" id="2C" value=""/>
      </li>
     </ol>
    </li>
   </ol>
 </div>
 <script  src="includes/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `value` atrribute which, I assume with be `value=""`

```css
input[value=""] {
  background: red;
}

input {
  background: lightgreen;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="cabin fuselage">
  <li class="row 1">
    <ol class="seats">
      <li class="seat"> No Value
        <input type="button" id="1A" value="" />
      </li>
      <li class="seat"> With Value
        <input type="button" id="1B" value="I have a Value" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It's what you initially asked but there is no CSS method of changing the parent `li`

Comment: Yeah, sorry and i hope you can understand if your answer isnt the marked one. Next time ill put up all information right away :)